# Change the position of the sort button in a grid in Tapestry 5

Tags: java, css, grid, tapestry

How do I change the position of the sort button in header of the grid in Tapestry 5?

I have column names of different lengths and I break lines on spaces, so the button, which is appended to the end of the column names, always ends up in different height. And that is very ugly :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default position is defined in default.css:

```
img.t-sort-icon {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

You can easily change it by providing a more specific CSS rule, e.g.

```
th img.t-sort-icon {
   //your style here
}
```

Comment: That't the right css property, Thanks. However I wasn't able to use it so the button would have the same height in all the columns.